# How to Calculate mean, median, max and min values for group by 15 days without outlier effect in R

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers

I have data of various machines which looks something like the one in the pic given below Input Sample Data

[Input Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5LTq.png)

What I need to do is calculate mean, median, max, and minimum based on groups created by every 15 days eg: group 1 = July 1-15 , group 2 = July 15-31, etc. But while calculating the data it should not consider the outlier values

the output should look like this
[Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqsLP.png)

i have used the following code to aggregate minute wise data to Day level first

```
DipDay = aggregate(Dipminute2[,c(4:18)], by=list(Dipminute2$Date), sum)
DipDay[,c(2:9)] = round(DipDay[,c(2:9)]*9*38/100000,2)
DipDay[,c(10:16)] = round(DipDay[,c(10:16)]*12*38/100000,2)
DipDay<-DipDay%>%rename("Date"="Group.1")
DipDay$Month = month(ymd(DipDay$Date) ,label = TRUE) 
DipDay$MonthNumber = month(ymd(DipDay$Date)) 
DipDay$Day = day(ymd(DipDay$Date)) 
DipDay$Biweek = as.factor(ifelse(DipDay$Day < 16, "1st_15_days", "last_15_days"))
DipDay$MonthBiweek = paste(DipDay$Month, "_", DipDay$Biweek)
Dip = DipDay[c(21,2:16)]
BiweekDip = aggregate(DipDay[c(2:16,18)], by=list(Biweek=DipDay$MonthBiweek), FUN=median)
BiweekDip = BiweekDip%>%arrange((BiweekDip$MonthNumber))
BiweekDipT= as.data.frame(t(BiweekDip[,c(1:16)]))
BiweekDipT= janitor::row_to_names(BiweekDipT,row_number = 1)
write.csv(BiweekDipT,"Fornightly Dipping Median Count.csv")
```

Sample input data looks like this for first 10 rows

```
    structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1593714765.03054, 1593714824.99918, 
1593714884.96776, 1593714945.01468, 1593715005.01454, 1593715064.98314, 
1593715125.03002, 1593715185.18608, 1593715244.99822, 1593715304.96657
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Kolkata"), Date = structure(c(18446, 
18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446
), class = "Date"), Time = c("00:02", "00:03", "00:04", "00:05", 
"00:06", "00:07", "00:08", "00:09", "00:10", "00:11"), `HCM 18` = c(7, 
8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7), `HCM 19` = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 
8, 8, 8), `HCM 20` = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 4, 8, 7, 7), `HCM 21` = c(8, 
7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8), `HCM 22` = c(8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 
8, 7, 7), `HCM 23` = c(8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8), `HCM 24` = c(7, 
7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, 0), `HCM 25` = c(8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
7, 8, 8), `HCM 54` = c(7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7), `HCM 55` = c(8, 
7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7), `HCM 56` = c(8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 
8, 8, 7), `HCM 57` = c(8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8), `HCM 58` = c(8, 
8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8), `HCM 59` = c(8, 1, 6, 8, 8, 7, 8, 
8, 7, 8), `HCM 60` = c(8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: How do you want to define outlier values?

Comment: Hi, we can define outliers values by less than 1  percentile value or greater than 99 percentile

Comment: Can you please make your question reproducible but posting useable data? We can't test code on a picture. `dput()` is the best way to share data, something like `dput(Dipminute2[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. `dput()` is best because it is copy/pasteable and preserves all class and structure information. See Ronak's link about how to give a good reproducible example if you need more help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
                   #Get month name
            mutate(month = format(Timestamp, '%b'), 
                   #get day of the month
                   day = as.integer(format(Timestamp, '%d')), 
                   #assign labels based on dat of the month
                   day = ifelse(day > 15, 'last_15', 'first_15')) %>%
  #combine month name and labels
  tidyr::unite(Biweek, month, day) %>%
  #For each 15 days
  group_by(Biweek) %>%
  #Change outliers to NA
  mutate(across(`HCM 18`:`HCM 60`, ~replace(., . < quantile(., 0.01) | 
                                           . > quantile(., 0.99), NA))) %>%
  #Calculate min, median, mean, max for each column for every 15 days.
  summarise(across(`HCM 18`:`HCM 60`, list(min = ~min(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           median = ~median(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           max = ~max(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: awesome, it actually worked perfectly well and did just give the right set of result

Comment: Hi team, for some weird reason, running the same code again i am getting the following error Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In names(cols)[missing_names] <- names[missing_names] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: You probably also have `plyr` loaded which is masking the `mutate` and `summarise` function. Restart R and load only `dplyr` library and try again.

Comment: Yes. i removed plyr package and it worked. thank you so much Ronak Shah